# iPhone custom Pop Up Message on Click in iPhone

Tags: iphone, popup

I am learning iPhone and i have seen a beautiful thing in ipHone builtin Photo Gallery.

In the image attached below i can see a small pop up (COPY) in black color is displayed on the pic.

I want some thing like this to implement in iPhone. Can anybody guide me??

Or atleast guide me that how can get the x,y coordinates of the Button i clicked on and then how would i display an image over that Button on the same co ordinates.

I hope you get what i am asking for

Thanks a bunch

Waiting for some positive response
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `UIMenuController`  controller to show the options and forgetting the coordinate of your `UIButton` use it's `frame` property.

Check the below blog post

http://ksylvest.com/post/471975163/cocoa-copy-paste-menu

http://intridea.com/2010/12/22/developers-notes-for-uimenucontroller

Answer (score 2):

Use [UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html). Since your button is a UIView you can easily get its position on screen.